# How to display "OEM extended ASCII" characters with PDCurses?

Tags: curses, pdcurses

I've been trying to display the "box characters" using PDCurses but for some reason they are not available in the character set. I used a loop to print all characters from 0x00 to 0xFF (through a call to the PDCurses function *printw("%c",index)*) and it gives me this:

[image]

I have no idea how to display the characters that should to be in the region where PDCurses displays the question marks in the example above. Does anyone know why this happens? If it's something about the codepage how can I change the codepage? Thanks!

**PS: I'm on Windows 7, and my program is compiled in MSVC 10.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print some box drawing characters using the curses ACS constants, like `ACS_ULCORNER`

In the [PDCurses Documentation](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/PDCurses.txt), search for "alternate character set".

You may need to use wprintw and `WACS_[whatever]`.